# Error Code-90161 Invalid provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, app-store-connect, xamarin.mac

> ERROR ITMS-90161:"Invalid Provisioning Profile

I have created IPA using Xamarin IOS in ad-hoc mode and selected a adhoc provisioning profile. but while uploading, following error annoying me :(

when I uploaded using application loader:

> ERROR ITMS-90161:"Invalid Provisioning Profile.The provisioning profile included in the bundle x.x.x.x[Payload/x.x.x.app] is invalid.[Missing code-signing certificate.] For more information,visit the iOS developer Portal."

Comment: You have to use Apple Store (not Ad-hoc) provisioning Profile while creating your .ipa in order to upload to AppleStore with APplication Loader.

Comment: Thanks a lot @HoaParis, but i wanted to submit for pre release testing via test flight beat testing. and unfortunately i don't have certificate to sign code in release mode while creating IPA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you get this error, you probably don't have the correct type of Provisioning Profile. There's a few types of Provisioning Profiles, most notably are the "Development" and "Distribution" profiles. I suggest looking at your provisioning profiles, and if necessary recreate them.

To elaborate: You have 1 Certificate (created via Xcode Certificate Generating). With this Certificate, you can create an "App Identifier", and Provisioning Profiles. You can use the same Certificate for both a Developer Provisioning Profile and a Distribution Provisioning Profile. They don't work with one another, meaning a Developer Provisioning Profile won't work for a release build, and a Distribution Provisioning Profile won't work for a debugg build.

Try this, and see if that helps. Be sure to haul the new profiles in Xcode (or any other method you'd use) and edit your project's settings.

Good luck!

Love and regards,
Björn

Comment: "Be sure to haul the new profiles in Xcode" sounds good, but how to do so?

Comment: Good description of the problem.  Sadly it's lacking a solution.

Comment: Please put a solution if someone found. I'm also having this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

My issue was related to having Xcode Automatically manage signing. What finally fixed the issue for me was going into the developer portal, selecting Certificates, and revoking the Distribution Managed certificate. I then rebuilt my project in Xcode, keeping the checkmark enabled to Automatically manage signing, and a new Distribution Managed certificate was automatically created in the developer portal under certificates. Distributing the archive to the App Store no longer produced any errors.

This issue also came up in other projects where I manually manage the Provisioning Profile. What worked for me was doing the following on the developer.apple.com portal:

1. Revoke the existing Distribution Certificate linked to the app's provisioning profile.
2. Issue a new Apple Distribution Certificate.
3. Link the new certificate to the app's provisioning profile.
4. Make sure to select the correct provisioning profile for your app's target in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks. This solved it for me. The issue suddenly crept up after a macOS update. I would've never guessed to do this.

Comment: Worked for me! Specific steps for the lazy or new: 
1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list
2. Click the Distribution managed certificate, and then click the red revoke button
3. Re archive and upload your app!

Comment: lol everyone seems to have this issue right now looking at the times of the comments…

Edit: I was a bit afraid to revoke my certificate, so I did the "certificate rotation" instead and I can report that works just as fine to resolve that problem

Comment: Revoking the Distribution Management certificate worked for me, too. Does somebody have an idea what caused this issue?
@DeveloBär: What is "Certificate rotation"?

Answer (score 6):

While de3z1e's solution seems to work for most people, it did not work for me. What did work was creating an Apple Distribution cert when using XCode settings. While Xcode is open,

`Go to preferences (Command + ,) -> Accounts -> Choose your team -> Manage certificates -> + (bottom left) -> Apple Distribution -> Re-archive + upload`

I am not sure why the other solution did not work for me, but this did. I also have Xcode manual signing on and left it on.

Answer (score 0):

For Distribution:

If you upload to Test Flight you need an Apple Store provisioning Profile.

If you are distributing to specific devices, you need Ad hoc provisioning profile.

You assign it in visual studio through Manual Provisioning, choosing an Apple Distribution Identity, and choosing your provisioning profile manualy - nothing in automatic.

If you like me could not find your newly created provisioning profile to appear in visual studio, make sure the bundile indetifier in info.plist is the same as used in the provisioning profile.

If you are white-labeling as per [xam-girls blog](https://xamgirl.com/white-labeling-in-xamarin-forms-applications/), other copies of info.plist is not looked at by visual studio iOS Bundle Signing

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. I edited profiles, it works.

Click edit button all provisioning profiles and save it. Download and use edited profiles. App will upload to store.