# Noob stuck in App Store Distribution upload

Tags: ios, flutter, certificate, provisioning

I'm a novice Flutter developer.  I just completed my first app.  I've managed to get it published to the Google Play Store internal testing process.  I'm attempting the same for iOS and macOS and TestFlight but I'm getting stuck when I try to upload for Distribution.  The error is a mismatch in the code signed versus the provisioning profile.  I've retraced and retried my steps multiple times, but I'm stuck.
Anyone willing to help me?
Thanks in advance,
JT

Comment: Please provide more details about the error, add error log.

Comment: from build:johntaylor@Johns-Air deep_iq % flutter build ios --release
Building co.taylorsoftware.deepiq for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team
in Xcode project: C6TRA59WM9
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         4.2s
Xcode build done.                                           26.9s
Built /Users/johntaylor/StudioProjects/deep_iq/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app.
johntaylor@Johns-Air deep_iq %

Comment: from Transporter:

Comment: ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle co.taylorsoftware.deepiq [Payload/Runner.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error, you probably don't have the correct type of Provisioning Profile. There's a few types of Provisioning Profiles, most notably are the "Development" and "Distribution" profiles. I suggest looking at your provisioning profiles, and if necessary recreate them.

To elaborate: You have 1 Certificate (created via Xcode Certificate Generating). With this Certificate, you can create an "App Identifier", and Provisioning Profiles. You can use the same Certificate for both a Developer Provisioning Profile and a Distribution Provisioning Profile. They don't work with one another, meaning a Developer Provisioning Profile won't work for a release build, and a Distribution Provisioning Profile won't work for a debugg build.

Try this, and see if that helps. Be sure to haul the new profiles in Xcode (or any other method you'd use) and edit your project's settings.

[Error Code-90161 Invalid provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960751/error-code-90161-invalid-provisioning-profile)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I eventually got it to work.  But I had to use manual vs automatic signing.  I'll keep at it.